# Oracle FULL OUTER JOIN three tables with two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

### Background

Oracle DB version:

```sql
SELECT * FROM v$version
WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';
-- OUTPUT
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

### Goal

I'm trying to outer join **three tables** with **two conditions** so that missing values simply appear as `NULL`. See the details below.

### Tables

The following tables are abstractions, so please don't try to improve on the data model itself.

#### MEASUREMENT

Primary Key = `ID`

```
|  ID  |    MEAS_NAME    |
|------|-----------------|
| 1000 | "Measurement 1" |
```

#### MEASUREMENT_AREA

Primary Key = (`ID`, `NAME`)
Foreign Key `ID` = `MEASUREMENT.ID`

```
|  ID  |    NAME   | AREA |
|------|-----------|------|
| 1000 | "Point 1" |   10 |
| 1000 | "Point 2" |   20 |
```

#### MEASUREMENT_VOLUME

Primary Key = (`ID`, `NAME`)
Foreign Key `ID` = `MEASUREMENT.ID`

```
|  ID  |    NAME   | VOLUME |
|------|-----------|--------|
| 1000 | "Point 1" |    100 |
| 1000 | "Point 3" |    200 |
```

### Expected Result

What I want is the following output:

```
|  ID  |    MEAS_NAME    |    NAME   | AREA | VOLUME |
|------|-----------------|-----------|------|--------|
| 1000 | "Measurement 1" | "Point 1" | 10   | 100    |
| 1000 | "Measurement 1" | "Point 2" | 20   | NULL   |
| 1000 | "Measurement 1" | "Point 3" | NULL | 200    |
```

This means, if for a specific `MEASUREMENT.ID` and a specific `NAME` there is both data in `AREA` and `VOLUME` then put them in the same line. Otherwise, just leave the `AREA` or `VOLUME` field empty.

#### Query 1

I came up with the following SQL statement, which **doesn't work**, it discards the results from `MEASUREMENT_VOLUME`:

```
SELECT meas.ID AS "ID",
    meas.MEAS_NAME AS "MEAS_NAME",
    COALESCE (area.NAME, vol.NAME) as "NAME",
    area.AREA, vol.VOLUME
FROM MEASUREMENT meas
  LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_AREA area
    ON meas.ID = area.ID
  FULL JOIN MEASUREMENT_VOLUME vol
    ON meas.ID = vol.ID AND area.NAME = vol.NAME
WHERE meas.ID = 1000;
```

#### Query 2

If I put `MEASUREMENT` last it works but the query is **very slow**:

```
SELECT meas.ID AS "ID",
    meas.MEAS_NAME AS "MEAS_NAME",
    COALESCE (area.NAME, vol.NAME) as "NAME",
    area.AREA, vol.VOLUME
FROM MEASUREMENT_AREA area
    FULL JOIN MEASUREMENT_VOLUME vol
        ON area.ID = vol.ID AND area.NAME = vol.NAME
    JOIN MEASUREMENT meas
        ON meas.ID = vol.ID OR meas.ID = area.ID
WHERE meas.ID = 1000;
```

### Questions

- Why does query 1 not work?
- Why does query 2 work?
- What's the most efficient way to achieve my output?

Your help is much appreciated, I'm not an SQL expert.

### Additional Information

- One row in `MEASUREMENT` contains meta data for exactly one measurement
- One measurement can contain hundreds of measurement points, which are distinguished by their `NAME.
- `MEASUREMENT_AREA` and `MEASUREMENT_VOLUME` are much bigger than `MEASUREMENT`, each of them contains more than 10 million rows

Comment: Could you please try this query ? `SELECT meas.ID,
    meas.MEAS_NAME,
    area.NAME,
    area.AREA, 
    vol.VOLUME
FROM MEASUREMENT meas
  LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_AREA area
    ON meas.ID = area.ID
  LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_VOLUME vol
    ON meas.ID = vol.ID AND area.NAME = vol.NAME
WHERE meas.ID = 1000;`
Could you please explain why your first query did not work ? What is the output ? Some pieces of advice : - you don't need to name the columns if they are already named the same way - you should put keys and indexes on columns used to find data between tables to optimize the search.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` was the first thing I tried, but it is guaranteed to not work. It misses out on any values which have a `NAME` which only exists in `MEASURMENT_VOLUME`. In my "Expected Result", row three would be missing, there is not `Point 3` in `MEASURMENT_VOLUME`. Unfortunately, this also happens with query 1. I don't know why, I expected a `FULL JOIN` to also take in values which do not match the condition `ON meas.ID = vol.ID OR meas.ID = area.ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically combined the answers of @dandarc and @thorsten-kettner (thank you very much for you valuable input):

Since `MEASUREMENT_VOLUME` and `MEASUREMENT_AREA` are much bigger than `MEASUREMENT`, I split up the JOINs:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM MEASUREMENT
  JOIN MEASUREMENT_AREA
    USING(ID)
  WHERE ID = 1000
)
FULL JOIN
(
  SELECT *
  FROM MEASUREMENT
  JOIN MEASUREMENT_VOLUME
    USING(ID)
  WHERE ID = 1000
) USING (ID, MEAS_NAME, NAME);
```

For my purposes it is important that the big tables are first joined to `MEASUREMENT` and then those results are combined (might as well work with `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY` as suggested by @dandarc).

This efficiently solves my problem. The `FULL JOIN` on three tables took more than 3 minutes with query 2. With this solution it takes seconds.

Note that my real life problem is more complicated since I have so select dozens of columns and can't simply use `SELECT *`. Thus, I can't use `USING(ID, MEAS_NAME, NAME)` but need to stick with the `ON` syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Why one query works and the other not has been explained in the other answer. So I just add how I'd write the query:

You want a full outer join of `measurement_area` and `measurement_volume`. Do this in a subquery and join with the `measurement` table:

```
select id, m.meas_name, data.name, data.area, data.volume
from measurement m
join 
(
  select id, name, ma.area, mv.volume
  from measurement_area ma
  full outer join measurement_volume mv using (id, name)
) data using(id);
```

Comment: +1 for using the `using` clause and avoiding redundant `nvl()` and such. It also possible that the OP needs a full outer join (or at least a left outer join) in the outer query, to account for "measurements" that are not present in either of the detail tables. But that's for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've also thought about splitting the JOIN explicitly. Your solution, however, doesn't work in my case, because `measurement_area` and `measurement_volume` are really big (up to 400 Million), so a FULL JOIN doesn't even fit into our temp space. But I've found a solution joining `measurement` and `measurement_area` first, `measurement` and `measurement_volume` second, and full joining the outcomes of the two. I'll post the solution.

Comment: Do you really need all measurements? In your example you limit it to one measurement (ID 1000). Once you add a `WHERE` clause to above query, there shouldn't be any issue, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I always limit to one measurement ID. However, adding a `WHERE ID = 1000` to the FULL OUTER JOIN doesn't help. It still takes minutes to compute the outcome. I'm not sure why. I'd have to analyse the execution plan. Since I have already found a solution that works, I won't do that. My guess is, that `USING(ID, NAME)` on the `FULL JOIN` computes to many rows which are filtered out afterwards with `WHERE ID = 1000`, but I really don't know.

Comment: Also note, that my solution uses an `(INNER) JOIN` first, which probably is more efficient to compute for the database including the `WHERE ID = 1000` condition. Note to self: only use `FULL JOIN` on very small tables.

Comment: Okay. Usually it suffices to add the `WHERE` clause at the end, as Oracle's optimizer is very good and sees to it to apply the criteria as early as possible. But there are always exceptions to the rule ;-) Glad, you found a solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Why does query 1 not work?**

```
...
ON meas.ID = vol.ID AND area.NAME = vol.name
...
where meas.ID = 1000
```

Your full join condition has area.name = vol.name which means on the row in the MEAS_VOLUME table with Name 'Point 3' does not match. With just the join, you do get the row from that table, but because it didn't match the condition, only the fields from that table have value - meas.ID is null along with MEAS_NAME and AREA. But then you filter out rows where ID does not = 1000. If you remove the where clause on that query, you get:

```
ID      MEAS_NAME       NAME    AREA    VOLUME
1000    Measurement 1   Point 1 10      100
                        Point 3         200
1000    Measurement 1   Point 2 20
```

**Why does query 2 work?**

Basically because it is correct for answering the question. Seems you recognized in that one that area.ID and vol.ID are not both available always, so you're matching MEASUREMENT to either in the join, which means your query works.

**What's the most efficient way to achieve my output?**

Without more information, this is hard to answer - what does your execution plan look like? What indexes are available? What are being used?

I'm guessing the full join is happening first, so you're doing that for 2 large tables, then joining back to the first table. Updating statistics on the tables might solve the performance issue with Query 2, or it may take deeper analysis than that.

Edited to Add - here's another correct version of your query that may execute faster than Query 2. Gets the OR out of the join conditions which sometimes makes life difficult for the optimizer.

```
with MEASUREMENT as
(
  select 1000 as ID, 'Measurement 1' as MEAS_NAME from dual
), MEASUREMENT_AREA as
(
   select 1000 as ID, 'Point 1' as NAME, 10 as AREA from dual union all
   select 1000 as ID, 'Point 2' as NAME, 20 as AREA from dual
), MEASUREMENT_VOLUME as
(
   select 1000 as ID, 'Point 1' as NAME, 100 as VOLUME from dual union all
   select 1000 as ID, 'Point 3' as NAME, 200 as VOLUME from dual
),
base_qry as (
    select meas.ID, meas_name, area.name, area, null as volume
    FROM MEASUREMENT meas
      LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_AREA area
        ON meas.ID = area.ID
    WHERE meas.ID = 1000

    union all 

    select meas.ID, meas_name, vol.name, null, volume
    FROM MEASUREMENT meas
      LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_VOLUME vol
        ON meas.ID = vol.ID
    WHERE meas.ID = 1000)
select ID, MEAS_NAME, NAME,
    max(AREA) as AREA,
    max(VOLUME) as VOLUME
from base_qry
group by ID, MEAS_NAME, NAME
order by 1,2,3
;
```

Comment: @gucce This demonstrates the difference between filtering based on `JOIN` criteria vs using a `WHERE` clause. Your `FULL JOIN` probably joined all the rows correctly, but then you excluded any row that's not `WHERE meas.ID = 1000`. `INNER JOIN`s don't make a difference in results, but `OUTER JOIN`s can, as you've seen.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying why query 1 doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
SELECT meas.ID AS "ID",
meas.MEAS_NAME AS "MEAS_NAME",
COALESCE (area.NAME, vol.NAME) as "NAME",
area.AREA, vol.VOLUME
FROM MEASUREMENT meas
LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_AREA area
ON meas.ID = area.ID
LEFT JOIN MEASUREMENT_VOLUME vol
ON meas.ID = vol.ID
WHERE meas.ID = 1000;
```

Simply remove the `area.NAME = vol.NAME` from your first query.

Comment: Then I won't get the values joined where the `NAME` matches, which is what I want. See "Expected Result" row one (`Point 1`), it has both `VOLUME` and `AREA` filled. Not using the `NAME` condition joins too much, I'd get two `Point 1` rows, one with only `AREA` filled, the other with only `VOLUME` filled.